# Why are items being placed below?

Tags: html, css

This is really confusing and I have never had this occur.

For my computer, it is fine. But for anyone else's computer I have tried, it screws up.

So on my site, designatease.com , the second bar down, it places the fifth item down below the first four. I am not sure why it is doing this. I want them to span across the bar but the stop at about half way. Help me out SOF.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Design At Ease - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><a class="logoclass">DesignAtEase.com</a></div>
<ul id="headerlinks">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="coding.html">Coding</a></li>
<li><a href="graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
<li><a href="database.html">Database</a></li>
<li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul id="quicklinks">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a></li>
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
background:#fffffc;
margin: auto auto;
}

#header{
background:#e5e5e5;
height:35px;
width:100%;
border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
}

#headerlinks{
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:right;
margin-right:5%;
bottom:37px;
}

#headerlinks li{
display:inline;
padding-left:25px;
}

#headerlinks li a{
color:#777777;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#headerlinks li a:hover{
color:#a3a3a3;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#logo{
position:relative;
color:black;
margin-left:5%;
top:5px;
}

.logoclass{
color:#212121;
display:inline;
font-size:24px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#quicklinks{
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;;
height:25px;
background:#e5e5e5;
border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
top:-16px;
position:relative;
}

#quicklinks li{
display:inline;
}

#quicklinks li a{

}

#quicklinks li a:hover{

}

#wrapper{
width:80%;
height:100%;

}
```

Comment: in what browser are you working, and what browser are you checking on other computers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with browser width.  Try grabbing the edge of your browser and moving it in and out to see the effect of your design on different canvas sizes.

The problem is the quicklinks div is colliding with the right-floated menu.  Use:

```
#quicklinks {
  clear: right;
}
```

..in your css to correct the issue.  Looks like you'll still have some vertical spacing to work out, but that will get you on the right track.  More info about *clear* here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 0):

A `clear: both;` for `#quichlinks` solves the problem.

As it looks, the below set will do the work for you:

```
#quicklinks{
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;;
height:25px;
background:#e5e5e5;
border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
top:-16px;
position:relative;
}
```

Hope it helps